# How to return objects from function in ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

Without ARC I can use autorelease for the Array as shown below

```
//-(NSMutableArray *)getObjects 

-(NSMutableArray *)retrieveObjects
{
    NSMutableArray *aArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   // add objects
   return [aArray autorelease];
}
```

How to achieve the same in ARC?

Comment: Note that, according to Cocoa’s naming conventions, you should only use method names starting with `get` when they return values via output parameters. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's [*Advance Memory Management Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

> In Automatic Reference Counting, or ARC, the system uses the same reference counting system as MRR, but it inserts the appropriate memory management method calls for you at compile-time. You are strongly encouraged to use ARC for new projects. If you use ARC, there is typically no need to understand the underlying implementation described in this document, although it may in some situations be helpful.

Typically you won't need to use retain, release, or autorelease methods. The system will do it for you. However, you need to be careful not to perform retain cycles; if you do, those objects will not be released ever.

Answer (score 8):

You don't `autorelease` the object.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do anything.  ARC will autorelease the array automatically because your method is named `getObjects` instead of being named something like `allocObjects` or `copyObjects` or `newObjects`.

Read [“Retained return values”](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retained-return-values) and [“Unretained return values”](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#unretained-return-values) in clang's documentation for details.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to autorelease that object. ARC will take care of it. However if nothing is strongly referred to the returned object from `getObjects` method it will get released immediately.

```
array = [self getObjects] // array should be a strong variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Like that :

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getObjects
{
    NSMutableArray *aArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   // add objects
   return aArray;
}
```